# asp.net mvc model - my own database

Tags: database

The tutorials I have come across usually let you create a dababase from scratch creating a .mdf file or something and so on.  However, what if I already have a SQL Server Express set up with the needed database? How do I tell my model to use that database?

Right now, all my model contains is basically some classes that execute stored procedure on my own database and return manupulated data.  Should I leave it as it is?  What are the benefits of going through the full-fledged model approach that tutorials demonstrate?

Comment: Are you using an ORM tool, such as LINQ-to-SQL or nhibernate?

Answer (score 1):

I am not using any ORM tool, but I am using Microsoft's Enterprise Library (Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary) to connect to the database. I would switch to an ORM tool, if that means performance boost. Otherwise, Microsoft Enterprise Library seems fine.